# Bash script to find files based on filename and do search replace on them

Tags: macos, bash, replace

I have a bunch of files (with same name, say abc.txt) strewn all over the network filesystem.

I need to recursively search for each of those files and once I find each one, do a content search and replace on them.

After some research, I see that I can find the files using the find command (with -r to recurse right?).  Something like:

```
    find . -r -type f  abc.txt
```

And use sed to do find and replace on each one:

```
    sed -ie 's/search/replace/g' abc.txt
```

But I'm not sure how to glue the two together so that I find all occurrences of abc.txt and then do a search/replace on each one.

My directory tree is really large so I know a recursive search through all the directories will take a long time but that's better than manually trying to find each file.

I'm on OSX 10.6 with Bash.

Thanks all!

Update:  I think the answer posted below may work for other OSes (linux perhaps) but for OSX, I had to tweak it a bit.

```
    find . -name abc.text -exec sed -i '' 's/search/replace/g' {} +
```

the empty quotes seem to required after a -i in sed to indicate that we don't want to produce a backup file.  The man page for this reads:

-i extension:

Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -r -type f abc.txt -exec sed -i -e 's/search/replace/g' {} +
```

Comment: Only thing missing is a `\;` or `+` on the end of the `-exec` clause... and copying the original poster's use of `-ie` rather than `-i -e` might have unintended effects, as the former specifies `e` as a file extension to use for backups.

Comment: Thanks amit_g! All of it is clear to me except the very end. What does the {} + do at the end?

Comment: {} is place holder for the filename and + ends the command and indicates to find to pass as many parameters as it could to the command so it runs the command far less number of times (compared to \;).